# Cree un App Script dentro de un Sheets que automatice la personalización de un Google Slides

Tags: google-apps-script

he creado un AppSheet que automatice un google slides, pero tengo un gran problema y es que al momento de correrlo aparece el siguiente mensaje:

Exception: Esta presentación está cerrada; los contenidos no pueden actualizarse.

He abierto el documento (puse el acceso en modo público) porque pensé que ese era el problema y también me convertí en propietario del documento.

No se porque puede estar sucediendo. Alguien tiene algún código que les funcione para hacer lo que les pido o una solución a mi problema.

El código que he creado es:

```
function onOpen(){
   const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
   const menu = ui.createMenu('Automatizaciones de App Script');
   menu.addItem('Crear Kick Off','CrearNuevosGoogleSlides');
   menu.addToUi();
}
function CrearNuevosGoogleSlides() {
const googleSlideTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('XXXYYYY');
const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('XXXYYY');
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Datos_Empresas');
 const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
 rows.forEach(function (row, index){
   if(index === 0) return;
   if(row[1]) return;
   const copy = googleSlideTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[0]}- Kick Off`,destinationFolder)
   const slides = SlidesApp.openById(copy.getId())
   const presentation = slides.getSlides();

   presentation.forEach(function(slide){
    var shapes = slide.getShapes();
    shapes.forEach(function(shape){
      var textRange = shape.getText();
     textRange.replaceAllText('{{Generación de Reportes}}', row[2]);
     textRange.replaceAllText('{{% Generación de Reportes}}', row[3]);
     textRange.replaceAllText('{{Flujos Repetitivos}}', row[4]);
     textRange.replaceAllText('{{% Flujos Repetitivos}}', row[5]);
     textRange.replaceAllText('{{Recopilar Información}}', row[6]);
     textRange.replaceAllText('{{% Recopilar Información}}', row[7]);
     textRange.replaceAllText('{{Compartir Información}}', row[8]);
     textRange.replaceAllText('{{% Compartir Información}}', row[9]);
     textRange.replaceAllText('{{Cons| Fe}}', row[10]);
     textRange.replaceAllText('{{Cons | Hora}}', row[11]);
     textRange.replaceAllText('{{Q&A | Fecha}}', row[12]);
     textRange.replaceAllText('{{Q&A | Hora}}', row[13]);
     textRange.replaceAllText('{{Cierre | Fecha}}', row[14]);
     textRange.replaceAllText('{{Cierre | Hora}}', row[15])
   })

   slides.saveAndClose();
   const url = slides.getUrl();
   sheet.getRange(index+1,2).setValue(url)
 })
 }
)}
```

Comment: En que linea del codigo muesta el error?